# Is it possible to copy CSS line number in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css, debug, firefox-developer-tools

It is really annoying to remember and type in line numbers of CSS rules, maybe there is some way to navigate quickly to the right line directly in my IDE? I can't believe nobody has an issue like this.

[image]

Comment: what's your IDE ?

Comment: @1NN PHPStorm..

Comment: How is the "right line" defined?

Comment: You'll probably best off with a plugin: [see here](https://www.oliviertravers.com/phpstorm-browser-dev-tools/)

Comment: @harrymc scss map file